# passing a run parameter to a downstream job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

Let's say I have a pipeline with a run parameters like this:

downstreamJob:

```
pipeline {
  parameters {
    run(name: 'NAME', filter: 'STABLE', projectName: 'myProject)
  }
}
```

Now, how can I use this job from another job and pass a run parameter?

Main job:

```
pipeline {
  parameters {
    run(name: 'NAME', filter: 'STABLE', projectName: 'myProject)
  }
  stages {
    stage('stage 1') {
      steps {
         build(job: "downstreamJob",
           parameters: [
             run(name: 'NAME', value: NAME)])
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Error:

```
WARNING: Unknown parameter(s) found for class type 'hudson.model.RunParameterValue': value

Could not instantiate {job=downstreamJob, parameters=[@run(name=NAME,value=http://.....)]} for org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.BuildTriggerStep: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate {name=NAME, value=http://.....} for hudson.model.RunParameterValue: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution was to call the downstream job with:

```
run(name: 'NAME', runId: NAME_JOBNAME + NAME_NUMBER)
```

They are environment variables and runID will be in the format: myProject#0